# Script to grab value from divs, compare if its a time value, then add it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm on this page: http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-iphone-app-ios7-2#getting-started

**goal**

If statement that if it is a value matching `[0-9]|[0-9]:[0-9][1-9]`, then add it along with the rest of the times and spit out a final time in HH:MM:SS. I can add all these times up by hand, but then I remembered I'm a programmer, so now I'm trying to write a script.

I tried:

`if this.val() == ...`

But it gave me an error for `this` so I don't know where to begin.

---

Basically I want to write a script to calculate the total time.

```
$('.achievement-steps ul li a p').each(function(index){

})
```

returns:

```
[
<p>​2:13​</p>​
, 
<p>​1 objective​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:23​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​6:19​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:05​</p>​
, 
<p>​10:12​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​5:27​</p>​
, 
<p>​2 objectives​</p>​
, 
<p>​1:16​</p>​
, 
<p>​1:20​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​12:25​</p>​
, 
<p>​1 objective​</p>​
, 
<p>​6:58​</p>​
, 
<p>​5:47​</p>​
, 
<p>​3 objectives​</p>​
, 
<p>​3:24​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​6:00​</p>​
, 
<p>​5:42​</p>​
, 
<p>​8:25​</p>​
, 
<p>​3 objectives​</p>​
, 
<p>​8:27​</p>​
, 
<p>​4 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:18​</p>​
, 
<p>​1 objective​</p>​
, 
<p>​5:53​</p>​
, 
<p>​2:11​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​18:02​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:49​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:55​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​11:27​</p>​
, 
<p>​3 objectives​</p>​
, 
<p>​6:11​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:30​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:37​</p>​
, 
<p>​11:19​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
, 
<p>​7:08​</p>​
, 
<p>​5 questions​</p>​
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
// get texts
var textList = $('.achievement-steps ul li a p').map(
        function(index,element){return $(element).html();});
// filter by regex
var timeList = $.grep(textList,
        function(element,index){return element.match(/^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/)!=null;});
// split by ":"
var tmp = timeList.map(
        function(element){return element.split(":")});
// mins and secs
var mins = tmp.map(function(element){return element[0];}),
    secs = tmp.map(function(element){return element[1];});
// sum
var totalMins =  mins.reduce(function(a,b){return +a+(+b);});
var totalSeconds = totalMins * 60 + secs.reduce(function(a,b){return +a+(+b);});

console.log(Math.floor(totalSeconds/60) + 'Mins,' + totalSeconds % 60 + 'secs');
// 198Mins,43secs
```

*I'm trying to learn [jQuery.map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), [jQuery.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so this answer might be a little more complex than it should be.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to total the values from decimal place to HH:MM:SS.

I realise the goal is to just total the values. Hopefully someone can expand on my answer, sorry if it is of no use.

```
var total = 0;
$('p').each(function(index){
    if($(this).text().length <= 5){
        total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(':', '.'));
    }
});

//convert total to time value
var hours = Math.floor ( total );
var minutes = ((total - Math.floor ( total )) * 60);
var seconds = ((minutes - Math.floor ( minutes )) * 60);
var time = hours.toString() + ':' + 
           Math.floor (minutes).toString() + ':' + 
           Math.floor(seconds).toString();

$('div').text('Total ' + time);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X9rU7/)**

Answer (score 0):

I created a bookmarklet to find the times.  The template came from this site: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/

Create timer.js

```
(function(){

    // the minimum version of jQuery we want
    var v = "1.3.2";

    // check prior inclusion and version
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
        var done = false;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                done = true;
                initMyBookmarklet();
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        initMyBookmarklet();
    }

    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            $(".achievement-steps").find('p').filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().match(/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/);
            }).each(function() {

                alert($(this).text());
            });
        })();
    }

})();
```

Add a bookmark to your browser with this location, substituting <#YOURDOMAINHERE#> with the location where you will place the file.  For now you can use the file located on my domain http://scripts.snappersworld.com/timer.js to see it working.

```
javascript:(function(){var b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.src="<#YOURDOMAINHERE#> /timer.js?"+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(b)})();
```

Load the page you want to parse, then click the bookmark you created.  It will pop an alert for each line that is a time.  The rest of the implementation is up to you